# his and her thing or things?

Tags: possessives

This might be a duplicate, so kindly excuse me if it turns out to be the case.

Do we say "This is his and her height" ? To me it sounds correct, but since we are talking about two separate heights, does my quoted phrase imply that it is both heights added together? (Nobody ever says that, i know)

For example if I say "His and her lexicon" does it mean the accumulated lexicon of Him + Her or is it treated as a separate one for each? Would you ever under any circumstance say "His and her lexicons?"

Perhaps "His and hers lexicon"?

Also, should I tag this under "grammar" or "grammaticality"?

Thank you!

Comment: If the "thing" is singular, then it belongs to both ("Frank and his sister's dad is cool"), if it's plural, they may each have part of them ("Frank and his friend's dads are friends"), or they all belong to both ("Frank and his brother's parents are in love"). And for your last suggestion, you can say "This lexicon is his and hers", but not "His and her**s** lexicon".

Comment: Thank you for answering. So if I want to say "the lexicon of each of them" (not both) should I go for "his and her lexicons"?

Comment: "His and her lexicons" will be ambiguous. If you wanna make it clear that they are different for each of them, then I would say "His and her **respective** lexicons." In this case however, both him and her may own one or more lexicons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"This is his and her height" would only be correct if they had the same height (i.e. 1 height).
In the same way you would not say "this is his and her name" unless they had the same name.

You could makes it "**these** are his and her **heights**" (these agreeing with the plural heights).

Or "this is a record of his and her height" or "this is a record of his and her heights" (in either case the 'this' refers to the singular record), since the "this" you are referring to is probably a thing, a piece of paper or a computer file, where the heights are recorded.